# How can I make the link divs to fill the navigation container?

Tags: html, css, web-deployment

I am trying to develop a web page that can be responsive to screen size. However I cannot figure out a way to do this and to fill the nav div with the link divs. I have a screen shot below and code to follow. There is also an issue with small screen sizes and the link divs. I would like the divs to shrink with the screen and not stack on top of each other. At least until a certain point. Information about this would be helpful as well. Also, explaining why these things happen helps a lot as well so if you like. Then please tell.
[image]
[image]

HTML:

```
<nav id="nav">
            <a href="FYFHome.html" ><div id="link"><p>Home</p></div></a>
            <a href="FYFHome.html" ><div id="link"><p>Services</p></div>      </a>
            <a href="FYFHome.html" ><div id="link"><p>Our Customers</p></div></a>
            <a href="FYFHome.html" ><div id="link"><p>Contact</p></div></a> 
        </nav>
```

CSS:

```
#link
{
    height: 70%;
    width: 25%;
    display: inline-block;
    border: 1px dotted green;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-align: center;
    padding: none;
}

#nav
{
    border: 1px solid black;
    width: 100%;
    height: 80px;
    margin: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add [`float:left`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/float)

```css
*{box-sizing: border-box;}

#nav {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 80px;
  margin: auto;
}
#link {
  height: 70%;
  width: 25%;
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;/*add this*/
  border: 1px dotted green;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: center;
  padding: none;
}
```

```html
<nav id="nav">
  <a href="FYFHome.html">
    <div id="link">
      <p>Home</p>
    </div>
  </a>
  <a href="FYFHome.html">
    <div id="link">
      <p>Services</p>
    </div>
  </a>
  <a href="FYFHome.html">
    <div id="link">
      <p>Our Customers</p>
    </div>
  </a>
  <a href="FYFHome.html">
    <div id="link">
      <p>Contact</p>
    </div>
  </a>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nzrsnp0b/)

25% would fit, but since you add 2 pixels border (1px left and 1px right) to your div, it is too wide. The best way to include the border (or padding and margin) is the `calc()` function, so use `calc(25% - 2px)`. 
The next issue is the white space between the divs. They are there because of the spaces / line breaks between the elements. Just add the end tag of one element in the line of the next one (or simply just the `>`)

```
<nav id="nav"> 
 <a href="FYFHome.html"><div id="link"><p>Home</p></div></a
 ><a href="FYFHome.html"><div id="link"><p>Services</p></div></a
 ><a href="FYFHome.html"><div id="link"><p>Our Customers</p></div></a
 ><!-- No more line breaks or spaces between the elements --><a href="FYFHome.html"><div id="link"><p>Contact</p></div></a> 
</nav>
```

To change the CSS for smaller screens just add to your style file

```
@media screen and (max-width: 320px) { 
    /* Your CSS for screens smaller than 320px */
}
```

You can add as many of those as you like, so you could have different CSS-styles for different screen sizes.